# Laravel Website on local server is showing error (The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again. )

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

My Website is working fine on hosting server, but when I downloaded all files and want to make changes on local server is showing error on submitting the form. All form has **CSRF Token**

```
The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again.
```

I have cleared cache, route, and even generate a new key by the following command.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan generate:key
```

Comment: Please check the POST request header and make sure that token is passed correctly and session life time in your .env file

Answer (score 0):

Run composer update
If still not work navigate to bootstrap - > caches and delete files present in it.

To test if token is passing use network tab in inspect element of browser.